# Finding latitude and longitude limits for a sub-region for CDS Copernicus Climate Data

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, climate, region, copernicus

In order to extract climate data from Copernicus, there's a Sub-region extraction section that allows one to extract data from a region within specific coordinate limits. I am trying to use the Sub-region extraction section specifically from [ERA5 hourly data on single levels from 1940 to present](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=form)

I am wondering how should one convert the latitude and longitude limits for a specific sub-region. For example, I have the coords 33.4483771, -112.0740373 and 35.56692889, -119.8946216. What should one do in order to find its North, South, East and West limits?